# allocatable arrays as part of derived types

Tags: fortran

Using Intel Visual Fortran XE 2013 (with 2003 syntax enabled) and Visual Studio 2012

I have a derived type with an allocatable array as a component. When I try to allocate an the array or set the allocatable array equal to an array, it doesn't seem to work. There is no error, but the values don't seem to be present.

Below is an example that should illustrate the issue.

```
Type myType
    integer :: var1, var2
    real*8,dimension(:), allocatable :: listOfReals
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: listOfInts
end Type myType

function setTheValues(someParams) result(typeA)

    type(params_T), intent(in) :: someParams
    type(myType_T) :: typeA

    type(lists_t)  :: lists 

    typeA%var1 = 1
    typeA%var2 = 2
    !where getList is a function that returns an 
    !object with an array of real numbers and an array of ints
    lists = getLists(someParams)
    typeA%listOfReals = lists%reals
    typeA%listOfInts = lists%ints

end function setTheValues
```

this doesn't work. neither does:

```
function setTheValues(someParams) result(typeA)

    type(params_T), intent(in) :: someParams
    type(myType_T) :: typeA

    type(lists_t)  :: lists


    typeA%var1 = 1
    typeA%var2 = 2

    allocate(typeA%listOfReals(12))
    allocate(typeA%listOfInts(12))

    !where getList is a function that returns an 
    !derivedtype with an array of real numbers and an array of ints both of size 12
    lists = getLists(someParams)
    typeA%listOfReals = lists%reals
    typeA%listOfInts = lists%ints

end function setTheValues
```

I either get something saying the values are not present, it won't show me any values, or it gives me an array with what appear to be enormous random index values with bad data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I am doing similar things in other parts of the code and they seem to be working right even though the debugger still seems to be having problems displaying the values right.

Comment: For the first case, do you `assume realloc_lhs`?  Beyond that, can you give a more complete example, in particular, what says "the values are not present"?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what assume "realloc_lhs" is. The VS2012 debugger says undefined address for the value with a big X.

Comment: A compiler option (although I'm not familiar with VS): without it set (and the default is not) automatic (re-)allocation doesn't happen.  Your first example (at least) is relying on this F2003 feature.

Comment: From within Visual Studio, the way to enable the reallocate on assignment language feature (/assume:realloc_lhs is the equivalent command line option for this) is to set the project property Fortran > Language > Enable F2003 semantics to "yes".  This changes some things other than just reallocation on assignment.

Comment: I have F2003 semantics set to yes as my question said.

Comment: @TheComposer My apologies; my non-familiarity with VS meant I couldn't equate the two concepts.

Comment: no worries. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what I did, but that part is working now, although the debugger cannot for some reason show the values of an allocatable array within a type within a type. Just so people know.

Answer (score 1):

```
module MyStuff

use, intrinsic :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV

implicit none

type myType
    integer :: var1, var2
    real (real64), dimension(:), allocatable :: listOfReals
end Type myType

contains

function setTheValues () result(typeA)
   type (myType) :: typeA

   typeA % var1 = 1
   typeA % var2 = 2

   allocate ( typeA % listOfReals(12))
   typeA % listOfReals = getList()

end function setTheValues

function getList ()

   real (real64), dimension (12) :: getList
   getList = [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0 ]

end function getList

end module MyStuff


program MyProg

use MyStuff

implicit none

type (myType) :: myType1

myType1 = setTheValues ()

write (*, *) myType1 % var1, myType1 % var2
write (*, *) myType1 % ListofReals

end program MyProg
```

Comment: Is there a reason you just rewrote my code while changing it to identical syntax. The change did not appear to do anything different. As I mentioned before this code only is supposed to show the issue. This is not in anyway my code. In my actual code my type has 15 allocatable arrays, 10 non allocatable arrays, and like 20 or thirty other fields. I need to know why I am having the issue. Especially since I'm not having an issue elsewhere in code where I thought I was doing the same thing.

Comment: This code works in gfortran and ifort.  Its a complete working example, rather than a fragment. And if you look at it carefully, there is a difference.

Comment: okay. I don't understand why you want me to hunt for the change, but I already noticed the differences. I changed them. It didn't fix it. You are using the ISO_FORTRAN_ENV intrinsic which lets you use the real64 syntax which doesn't change anything about my code that I am aware of. I also see you changed everywhere I am accessing a field of a derived type to have a space on either side of it which I will say I didn't know you could do. I don't know why I would want to though unless it actually does something different which I don't know because you didn't say anything about it.

Comment: I was trying to have you figure it out but maybe I was being opaque.  Sorry.  Your question has been edited several times so I'm not sure now but I think the key change is `allocate ( typeA % listOfReals(12))`.  That is why the comments were asking about `assume realloc_lhs`.  Fortran 2003 will automatically allocate/reallocate on assignment (see 3.3 of ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1551-N1600/N1579.pdf) but AFAIK this is not enabled by default in ifort.

Comment: is there some difference between allocate(typeA%listOfReals(12)) and allocate ( typeA % listOfReals(12)) that I am not aware of?

Comment: No.  Many think the spaces improve readability.  I think originally you didn't have the `allocate`.  That was what initiated the discussion of `assume_realloc_lhs`.  The `allocate` is unnecessary in Fortran 2003.

Comment: It was originally in the second example.